# Maven produces uncompilable source code when I add throwable clauses to overridden methods

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

This is the second time this happened to me which leads to the conclusion that it's either Maven bug or happens because I don't use Maven properly.

What I did it that I created an abstract class:

```
public abstract class A {
  public abstract void doSomething();
  //Non abstract methods follow
}

public class Aimpl extends A {
  @Override
  public void doSomething() {...};
}
```

Later on I added threads and I need this `doSomething` to throw `InterruptedException`. I added it to both method definitions:

```
public abstract class A {
  public abstract void doSomething() throws InterruptedException;
}

public class Aimpl extends A {
  @Override
  public void doSomething()  throws InterruptedException {...}
}
```

After pressung Run in Netbeans, I got `Uncompilable code` errors in the output. After pressing clean build they were gone. Is this what should be happening? Shouldn't I configure something in NetBeans to prevent this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that Compile on Save feature played tricks on you. NetBeans will compile your changes for you on the fly. Later on if you do just mvn install (without clean) maven will not compile anything, as it believes the class files are all good.

It's possible to disable it (in project's Properties dialog) but most of the time it's useful and works.